# display non matching dropdown selection list while typing special character like ! and @

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I am facing issue while angular bootstrap ui typehead display dropdown result while typing !!(two times ! or four times!) and !@(combination). i try to add filter but with filter doesn't work correctly only shows value which are in cache or so. i want if the user types any special character it doesn't display any suggestion

plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/E0IiqNTsgp0sP5Yggyau?p=preview
[image]

filter in controller

```
 $scope.startsWith = function (state, viewValue) {
            //var pattern = new RegExp(/[~`!@#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/); //unacceptable chars
            var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/;
            if ((pattern.test(viewValue))) {
                return true; 
           }
        }
  $scope.states= ['Alabama','california','Texas'];
```

html

```
<input type="text" uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue:startsWith | limitTo:3" autocomplete="off" >
```

what should i make change that when use type any time special character iike !! or !!!! or !@ or anyhthing like prevent displaying non match result.

i tried every other thing to make it working but not. appreciate if some can reply immediate

Answer (score 0):

The `var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;` should do the trick, matches only words. Maybe you need to prevent the user from entering special characters at all, something like:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]" />
```

Comment: I tried with ng-pattern and also pattern. it doesnt work please check attached plunker link. i quickly edit but not working.